# How do I fix "ICDauthority" error on login?

Tags: boot, login

When I go to log in  this error code appears:

```
Could not update ICDauthority file /home/james/.ICEauthority
```

I have tried using `chown james:james /home/james/.ICEauthority` followed by `chmod 644 /home/james/.ICEauthority` in the root menu, but this was unsuccessful.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the file and reboot. The system will recreate the file with the user permissions that is used to logon.

I have seen this happen when I used `root` access on my home directory where the system sets the permissions of the file to root and the user then (ofcourse) can not set these back.